# Json With Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Tried a program -if json file already exists do nothing and if it does not exist then ask for input and write that input to file.Error is coming when I give input

```
import json
name="first.json"
try:
   r=open(name)
except FileNotFoundError:
   e=open(name,"w")
   a=input("Enter Name: ")
   json.dump(e,a)
```

Comment: "Error is coming" - what's the error?

Comment: Enter Name: a r=open(name)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'first.json'

Comment: in function "json.dump(e,a)" first parameter is object to dump and second one is file object

Comment: Also,During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback
  line 10, in <module>
    json.dump(e,a)
  File "C:.....\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:......\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\....Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable

Comment: @user3431635 That was a very silly mistake of mine.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
name="test.json"
try:
    r=open(name)
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open(name,"w") as e:
        a=input("Enter Name: ")
        json.dump(a,e)
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.dump` takes data to be written into a file first and the file second.

So the code should be:

```
# json.dump(data, file)
json.dump(a,e)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is wrong input data. Script has not any error.
input `{"1": 1}` is worked